# Use T-SQL Merge to update existing records and insert records that don't exist but avoid duplicates

Tags: t-sql, merge, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-merge

I have two tables of identical structure t1 and t2.
Table t1 has approximately 100+ records more than t2.

Here's a small sample of t1.

```
| pid   | tid    | amt         | paymentdt  | paymentmnth   | startdate                 | enddate                   | updtby
| 670   | 1      | 690.00      | 2015-07-07 | 2015-07-07    | 2015-10-26 14:36:27.000   | 2015-10-26 15:42:42.000   | NULL
| 670   | 11     | 855.00      | 2015-07-07 | 2015-07-07    | 2015-10-26 14:36:27.000   | NULL                      | NULL
| 670   | 13     | 129.00      | 2015-07-29 | 2015-07-29    | 2015-10-26 14:36:27.000   | NULL                      | NULL
| 670   | 2      | 855.00      | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-01    | 2015-10-26 15:42:42.000   | NULL                      | NULL
| Z41   | 1      | 62.35       | 2015-05-08 | 2015-05-08    | 2015-10-26 10:15:24.000   | 2015-10-26 13:08:05.000   | NULL
| Z41   | 11     | 800.00      | 2015-05-08 | 2015-05-08    | 2015-10-26 10:15:24.000   | NULL                      | NULL
| Z41   | 2      | 298.00      | 2015-06-01 | 2015-06-01    | 2015-10-26 13:08:05.000   | 2015-10-26 14:36:27.000   | NULL
| Z41   | 3      | 298.00      | 2015-07-01 | 2015-07-01    | 2015-10-26 14:36:27.000   | 2015-10-26 15:15:45.000   | NULL
| Z41   | 4      | 298.00      | 2015-08-01 | 2015-08-01    | 2015-10-26 15:15:45.000   | 2015-10-26 15:42:42.000   | NULL
| Z41   | 5      | 238.00      | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-01    | 2015-10-26 15:42:42.000   | NULL                      | NULL
```

And a small sample of t2.

```
| pid   | tid    | amt         | paymentdt   | paymentmnt   | startdate                 | enddate                   | updtby
| 670   | 1      | 690.00      | 2015-07-07  | 2015-07-07   | 2015-10-02 16:10:50.000   | 2015-10-02 16:35:50.000   | NULL  
| 670   | 11     | 855.00      | 2015-07-07  | 2015-07-07   | 2015-10-02 16:10:50.000   | NULL                      | NULL  
| 670   | 13     | 129.00      | 2015-07-29  | 2015-07-29   | 2015-10-02 16:10:50.000   | NULL                      | NULL  
| 670   | 2      | 855.00      | 2015-09-01  | 2015-09-01   | 2015-10-02 16:35:50.000   | NULL                      | NULL  
| Z41   | 1      | 298.00      | 2015-07-01  | 2015-07-01   | 2015-10-02 16:10:50.000   | 2015-10-02 16:23:26.000   | NULL  
| Z41   | 11     | 800.00      | 2015-05-08  | 2015-05-08   | 2015-10-02 16:10:50.000   | NULL                      | NULL  
| Z41   | 2      | 298.00      | 2015-08-01  | 2015-08-01   | 2015-10-02 16:23:26.000   | 2015-10-02 16:35:50.000   | NULL  
| Z41   | 3      | 238.00      | 2015-09-01  | 2015-09-01   | 2015-10-02 16:35:50.000   | NULL                      | NULL  
| 173   | 1      | 785.00      | 2015-07-01  | 2015-07-01   | 2015-10-02 16:16:30.000   | 2015-10-02 16:27:36.000   | NULL  
| 173   | 11     | 465.00      | 2015-05-01  | 2015-05-01   | 2015-10-02 16:16:30.000   | NULL                      | NULL
```

Now comparing t1 and t2 shows there are more values in t1 for pid `Z41` such as the tid's include 1, 2, 3, 4 5, and 11. But in t2 there exists only 1, 2, 3, and 11.

However the startdate's are completely different between t1 and t2 so this throws a wrench in things. Below is the merge I've tried but it basically just inserts every row with a different startdate from that of t1 in t2.

```
MERGE INTO t2 AS tgt
USING t1 AS src
    ON tgt.pid = src.pid AND
       tgt.tid = src.tid AND
       tgt.paymentdt = src.paymentdt AND
       tgt.paymentmnt = src.paymentmnt AND
       tgt.startdate = src.startdate
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        tgt.amt = src.amt,
        tgt.paymentdt = src.paymentdt,
        tgt.updatedby = 'MERGEDUPDATE'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (pid, tid, amt, paymentdt, paymentmnt, startdate, enddate, updtby)
    VALUES (src.pid, src.tid, src.amt, src.paymentdt, src.paymentmnt, src.startdate, src.enddate, 'MERGEDINSERT');
```

With this merge I am left with duplicates of `pid and tid` where the `updtby` column reads 'MERGEDINSERT'. But I want to avoid the duplicates.

> How do I correctly go about this merge to not produce duplicates but
>   insert the rows that exist in t1 but not in t2 while also updating the
>   `amt, paymentdt, and paymentmnth` values while keeping startdate?

Comment: May be remove dates and amount from ON clause? What is the desired output for data you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, your merge criteria should be based on `pid` and `tid` only . try this

```
MERGE INTO t2 AS tgt
USING t1 AS src
    ON tgt.pid = src.pid AND
       tgt.tid = src.tid 

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        tgt.amt = src.amt,
        tgt.paymentdt = src.paymentdt,
        tgt.paymentmnth  = src.paymentmnth, 
        tgt.updatedby = 'MERGEDUPDATE'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (pid, tid, amt, paymentdt, paymentmnt, startdate, enddate, updtby)
    VALUES (src.pid, src.tid, src.amt, src.paymentdt, src.paymentmnt, src.startdate, src.enddate, 'MERGEDINSERT');
```

Comment: Leaving only `pid` and `tid` in the `on` clause yields the following: `The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.`

Comment: @gh0st This means you are getting multiple matches for `pid/tid` combos. What is the desired output? Can you use MAX() on the dates?

Comment: Basically, I want to update any records in t2 with the matching records in t1 and if a `pid + tid` combination record does not exist I want to insert it.

Comment: But your error is saying that some `pid + tid` records exist more than once, so how do you know which values to use in the update?

Comment: Take for example record `pid = Z41, tid = 3` in t2. I want to update that record to match what is in t1 so that startdate and enddate is set to the corresponding values in t1. Then for records `(pid = Z41, tid = 4) and (pid = Z41, tid = 5)` I want to insert those records into t2.

Comment: @gh0st The error is saying, using your example, more than one record exists with `pid = Z41, tid = 4`

Answer (score 0):

If you're `MERGE` is throwing an error because of getting multiple records/matches, you can limit the Source table using aggregates within a subquery, e.g.:

```
;WITH t1cte AS (
    select pid, tid, amt, paymentdt, paymentmnt, startdate, enddate
    from t1 a
      inner join (select pid,tid,MAX(paymentdt) as maxdt from t1 group by pid,tid) b
        on a.pid = b.pid and a.tid = b.tid and a.paymentdt = b.maxdt
        )

MERGE INTO t2 AS tgt
USING t1cte AS src
    ON tgt.pid = src.pid AND
       tgt.tid = src.tid AND
       tgt.paymentdt = src.paymentdt AND
       tgt.paymentmnt = src.paymentmnt AND
       tgt.startdate = src.startdate
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        tgt.amt = src.amt,
        tgt.paymentdt = src.paymentdt,
        tgt.updatedby = 'MERGEDUPDATE'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (pid, tid, amt, paymentdt, paymentmnt, startdate, enddate, updtby)
    VALUES (src.pid, src.tid, src.amt, src.paymentdt, src.paymentmnt, src.startdate, src.enddate, 'MERGEDINSERT');
```

Comment: `Column 'dbo.t1.pid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Changed the `select` in the `inner join()` to `select pid, tid, max(paymentdt) as maxdt from t1 group by pid, tid`.

Comment: However still inserts duplicates because there's no match on `tgt.startdate = src.startdate`.